# I need a redirect rule that changes the query string

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, rules

How can I redirect MY_DOMAIN/search/?q=Orientation+Software to go to this URL: MY_DOMAIN/search/?term=Orientation+Software

Where the only thing that changes is "**q**" to "**term**"?

This is what I have come up with, but it does not work.

```
<rule name="RewriteToSearches">
  <match url="^search/?q=([0-9A-Za-z+])" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="search/?term={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. I did some quick testing so you may need to tweak it a little.

```
<rule name="RewriteToSearches">
  <match url="^search/(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="&amp;?q=(([^&amp;\?]+))&amp;?" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="search/?term={C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks :) I up-voted, but since I am a new member it does not show up.

Comment: You're welcome. But instead of upvoting you can accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks. This lets other visitor know that the answer is useful.